# Frugal thick table top ideas

Tags: woodworking, self-assembly-furniture

I'm trying to build a TV stand which will have a top on it about 80" x 20" x 3/4".  It can be thicker than 3/4" but I'd like it to be at least that.  Assuming I build a supportive frame, what's the cheapest way to get a piece that fits the bill?  I've looked at using plywood and edging as well as biscuit joining planks together, but would like to hear other ideas.

Comment: Depends on how finished you want it to look.  For a very rough table, you don't even need to join the tabletop planks - think of it the same as building a mini deck.

Comment: Edging can be thicker than the actual to, and often is, both to give the appearance of a thicker top and to improve its rigidity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A narrow slab door might fit the bill. 80" is a very common height. Architectural recycling places, such as Habitat For Humanity Restores (if you're in North America) have them for nearly nothing. 
If you get a hollow core and it's too wide, be aware that it's a bit fiddly to make it work well.

Comment: I really like this idea.  We just got a HfH Restore nearby and frequent it often!  I assume a solid core door I could rip to the appropriate width right?

Comment: Note that "solid" doors are solid (not hollow) but not not actually *solid wood*. If you rip a solid door to width you may expose particleboard filler.

Comment: You'd probably expose particle core, but you could either put that to the back or edge it with some thin veneer.